# Finding $c(p)$ s.t. $ \int_p^1 c(x)/x\ dx = c(p)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm searching for a function $c(p)$ that satisfies

$$ \int_p^1 c(x)/x\ dx = c(p)$$

Can I somehow transform this into a differential equation? How else to solve it?
If it can't be solved analytically, how would I solve it numerically?

Comment: Hint : Use the fundamental theorem of calculus and differentiate both sides with respect to $p$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $c$ is continuously differentiable, then we have
\begin{align}
-\frac{c(p)}{p}=\frac{d}{dp}\int^1_p \frac{c(x)}{x}\ dx = c'(p) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{c'(p)}{c(p)} =-\frac{1}{p}
\end{align}
which means
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dp}\log|c(p)|= -\frac{1}{p} \ \ \Rightarrow& \ \ \log|c(p)| = -\log|p|+C \\
\Rightarrow&\ \ c(p)=\frac{C}{p}. 
\end{align}

However, substituting the solution back into the original equation yields the following
\begin{align}
\int^1_p \frac{C}{x^2}\ dx = \frac{C}{p}-C = \frac{C}{p} 
\end{align}
i.e. $C=0$. Thus, your equation only has a trivial solution provided $c$ is continuously differentiable.